# Como puedo pegar manualmente codigo en un campo?

Tags: html, phpmyadmin

quiero crear una tabla en una base de datos para poder, en uno de los campos, pegar codigo html, este codigo varia de tamaño pero siempre tiene entre los 200.000 y 400.000 caracteres.

Yo lo quiero pegar manualmente con Phpmyadmin pero como para este tipo de campo el tipo es Blob, no me permite pegarlo sino que me solicita escoger un archivo.

Hay alguna otra forma de poder insertar manualmente codigo html de estas características mencionadas con Phpmyadmin?

Comment: Por qué querés pegar todo una página en la DB? Por ahí si nos explicás un poco más te podríamos dar otra solución.

Answer (score 0):

En PHpMyAdmin ve a la pestaña "SQL" y ahí dentro has el INSERT, debes asegurarte que las comillas con las que abres el valor que vas a insertar, no estén presentes en ese html.

el INSERT debe ser algo así:

`INSERT INTO nombredetutabla (nombrecolumna) VALUES ('<html> ... todo el resto de tu html sin usar comillas simples, solo comillas dobles ... </html>')`

He probado esto en un campo tipo BLOB y ha resultado sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego le das click al botón "Continuar" y es todo, solo asegúrate eso de las comillas para que no te tire error.

Comment: intenté de la forma que me dijiste pero me da ERROR. Igualmente de la forma que me decís es mas difícil, yo quiero pegar el HTML que es un DIV en el textarea del campo cuando voy a la pestaña INSERTAR, ahí lo pongo entre comillas dobles tambien, pero el error que me da es : campo x no tiene un valor por defecto.

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta y pega el código html que estás intentando insertar, así podré ver a qué se debe que no puedas hacerlo.

Comment: Es muy largo no puedo pegarlo aca y es html sin errores generado por software, es solo un DIV con otros elementos html comunes dentro, sin javascript.

Comment: Tengo wampserver, quizas haya que configuar algo para poder pegar textos grandes en Phpmyadmin.